# Multiplying power series

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to understand how the expression
$$
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^n \cdot \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^n
$$
results in the following expression:
$$
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (1+n)x^n.
$$
Could you please walk me through it?

Comment: what do you know about power series, perhaps include them? it would be good to include your attempt.

Comment: Note $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\dfrac1{1-x}$ if $\lvert x\rvert<1$; or collect terms with the same exponent

Comment: sorry but the above comments aren't helpful at all.

Comment: @Wingardium. The first comment is trying to get you to show what work you've done.  That's typically expected around here if you want an answer/help.  It helps to provide context: what do you know about series? what do you know about this particular problem? what concepts are you struggling with? etc.  The second one gives you a good hint. Try to use it!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just multiply it, like polynomials?

When polynomials, following is well-known: $\sum_0^na_ix^i\cdot\sum_0^mb_jx^j=\sum_{k=0}^{n+m}\sum_{i+j=k}a_ib_jx^k$.

Then modifying in power series, you can get...

$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i\cdot\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^j=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i+j=k}x^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+1)x^k
$$

Answer (score 0):

A simple observation might be enlightening:

$$(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x+x^2+x^3)\\
=1+x+x^2+x^3+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6\\
=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+3x^4+2x^5+x^6.$$